# how to add flow value in param tag?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visual-workflow

As i am trying to convert a flow in vf page,but when i convert the flow in vf page it is giving error like pages/sfdcflow.page: No variable named "Completed" in flow.
Flow i create to simply delete the records from list view page in lightning.
this is my flow :--[image]

and then add a fast lookup for take the all ids in a array
[image]

and for this this the sobject collection variable that i create for this:-
[image]

this is the vf page that  i create for it--

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="SFDC_Project__c" recordSetVar="SFDC Projects">
  <flow:interview name="SFDC_Del" >
      <apex:param name="Completed" value="{!SFDC_Project__c.id}" />
  </flow:interview>

</apex:page>
```

but it is always giving the error pages/sfdcflow.page: No variable named  "Completed"  i also tried like this:-

```
<apex:param name="sfdcCollect2" value="{!SFDC_Project__c.id}" />
```

but again giving error like no variable named  "sfdcCollect2" can i get some help that how can i set the variable for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@sonam use like this its working

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" 
  standardController="SFDC_Project__c" recordSetVar="SFDC Projects">
    <flow:interview name="SFDC_Del" >
    <apex:param name="sfdcCollect2" value="{!SFDC Projects}" />
   </flow:interview>

  </apex:page>
```

Comment: yes you are right i use it like this, but need to remove the space use like recordsetvar = 'SFDCProjects" and value ="{!SFDCProjects}" then it working fine.

Comment: can you please help me when after my code finish i want that it give me my customize message and and redirect on my home record page on lightning, for this i tried like finishLocation="{!IF($User.UITheme == 'Theme4d' || $User.UITheme == 'Theme4t','/one/one.app#/sObject/SFDC_Project__c/home','/500')}" ,but i guess this will not work in managed packaged and some hoe i want to show message also that after finish my message will show..can it possible?

Comment: @sonam use this function finishLocation="{!URLFOR before the your if condition exactly i dont know check it once

Comment: how can i set the message?

Comment: i try to create controller for this like :-